# Export grid to excel error

Tags: export

Getting issue while exporting grid to excel is "control of type 'button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server + Sharepoint 2010"

Comment: I think you need to add more details to this question, it is a bit hard to understand what the problem is right now

Comment: we want to export a grid view data to excel.In grid view we have button like "edit" , "delete" and link button.how can i export my grid to excel without columns which contain these buttons.i think due to these button i am getting error .Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this buttons to have a runat="server" tag and for exporting, only take the text of each row and not the controls. Something like this:

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
 {
                foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    String cellValue = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(cell.Text);
                }
 }
```

Comment: foreach (GridViewRow row in grdSalesOrders.Rows)
                {
                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                table.RenderControl(htmlwriter);

Comment: this is my code and getting error on last line while render control.

Comment: suppose i have 6 column in grdSalesOrders and i want only number 3,5 in table row. how can i do it ?i want the row which i am going to ad in table not contain that column which giving me error .

Comment: you only want those column going into the excel, right?

Comment: yes i want only column 3,5 .but how to add in table

Comment: you can for example select grid.Rows.Cells[0] . this would then be the value in the first column for this row